# Debug embedded software (coredump)

Tags: debugging, gdb, embedded, coredump

I'm currently working on an embedded CPU (ARM cortex-M0) on board. I'm experiencing crashes (HardFault) and thus, I'm trying to debug them.

Currently I can get a dump of the memory (I send everything in hex over the printf console, my only access to the memory).

My idea is to load that dump as coredump to gdb and thus being able to debug the program.
How is it possible to create a "real" coredump file from the raw memory dump, so that I can give it directly to gdb ?

I also tried to run my program in the gdb simulator to use the `restore` command with my raw memory but I don't understand how to run it. Do you have an idea ?

The main question here is in fact: How to create a coredump file that is compatible with gdb based on the program elf and the raw memory content ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use an on-chip debugger?

Comment: I doubt that a memory dump is sufficient; the register state would also be necessary.  There is a thread on this from 1999 at https://www.sourceware.org/ml/gdb/1999-q2/msg00065.html . By the time you get a hard-fault you are asking a lot for `printf` to still work in many cases - especially if it is buffered and interrupt driven.  A hardware debugger would be far more effective in this situation.

Comment: @Lundin The cortex M0 debugger is very expensive and not present on the board.

Clifford: Yes, I have the registers also and the printfs aren't actually printfs, just a write to an hardware FIFO.

Comment: @Gp2mv3 Not sure what you mean with "very expensive", $100? There's lot of cheap debuggers for Cortex M0. Nothing needs to be "present on the board" except a SWD connector.

Comment: @Lundin It's a bit more complicated. I'm working on a security chip that doesn't have debug capability for obvious security reasons. Thus the hardware debugger is not an option and is really expensive to add to the HDL design.

Comment: Custom practice for such projects is to have a debug version of the hardware. Or at least that's what I've done when I've worked with projects that involved security locks against reverse engineering. Even something as simple as an eval board + ICD + misc manually soldered junk will be better than debugging through printf. Particularly since stdio.h isn't used in production code.

Comment: A cortex-m0 debugger costs around $10 plus shipping, the software is free, not sure how that is cost prohibitive.

Comment: Your real problem is how do I debug this hardfault, not how do I use a memory dump.  And the answer is just use or develop normal debugging techniques.  Even with a debugger you may not find the problem, debuggers change the way the program runs and that may be related to the problem.  So you have to go through the normal cycle of examine your code, examine the docs, divide the problem in half and keep dividing until you find it.  A dump of the memory may only help with certain classes of problems.

Comment: Start by using your hex print function in the hard fault handler (you are dead anyway no point worrying about what you can and cant do in a handler) to dump the stack and find out what instruction (address) caused the fault, use a disassembly of your program to work backward from that, use the hex printf in that code space to print data/address values out to confirm they are what you think they are that lead up to the instruction in question.

Comment: @Gp2mv3: The debugger is for free is you use a modern and free toolchain. As you already mention, why not use gdb on the target? And there is no "cortex-M0 debugger" on the target. Just the embedded debug-IP-core. Which device is it not providing that? Security reasons don't inhibit debugging facilities. Typically they can be permanently deactivated e.g. by buring fuses.

Comment: The debug IP Core is not present and that's the expensive part. I'm trying to do exactly what @dwelch is saying but I thought there was a better solution with GDB for example. Without changing the HDL or adding more hardware.

Comment: confused, so you are running the rtl?  then just run it in a sim and look at the waveforms.

Comment: No I'm running on board.

Comment: Guys, it is not always practical to reproduce a problem with a debugger attached. Some bugs happen so infrequently that you see the issue in the field, but it is almost impossible to reproduce in the lab. In this scenario using some kind of coredump would be the only solution. A debugger connection would be the best solution if the bug is easily reproduceable, but otherwise a coredump is very useful.

Comment: @Gp2mv3 - you seem to be talking as if you are using an FPGA to implement the MCU? If you are using an M0+ microcontroller why would you need HDL or have a part that doesn't have debug?

Comment: The project was running on FPGA for development, then on ASIC. We implemented the MCU in the IP, but it was isolated and "cut from the outside" as it was dedicated to security tasks. The only access I had was the logs, in a FIFO. I'm not working on that project for a long time now. I don't remember the solution I found but it was not straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

There are a pair of libraries that will do this: [CrashCatcher](https://github.com/adamgreen/CrashCatcher) and [CrashDebug](https://github.com/adamgreen/CrashDebug).  This first prints a dump (which you are already doing but this prints in a specific format) and the second interfaces into gdb to allow loading the dump.  For some reason CrashDebug doesn't create a core file but rather interfaces into gdb using gdb's `target remote` command.  Same effect though.  It supports Cortex-M0, M3, and M4.